# Git an existing project

Tags: git

I am missing something. I am attempting to use Git with an existing project and get our team working with it. Following is what I did:

```
ssh user@domain.com
cd /directory/of/gitProject
git init
git add .
git commit 'First commit'
```

I then thought to bring it to my local, I would exit from the ssh connection, then from my local:
git clone user@domain.com/directory/of/gitProject/.git myLocalGit

When I do this, I get that it does not appear to be a git repository.

Comment: `I get that it does not appear to be a git repository. `??

Comment: are you using bitbucket, github, or something else

Comment: Try `git clone user@domain.com/directory/of/gitProject/` (don't select the .git folder)

Comment: Even if you were able to pull correctly you would'nt be able to push to the repo. A git repo as you are trying to use it must be initialized as a bare repository. So `git init --bare` had to be done.

Answer (score 1):

`.git` is not really a repository; the directory that *contains* it is. So you want to clone *that* directory, not `.git`.

By the way, when creating the repository on the server that you want to pull/push to/from, you should pass `--bare` to `git init`. Then make your first commit from your local machine, not on the server.

Comment: Thank you. This worked. You mention that the first commit should be from the local machine. However, I want to pull the full project from the server to my local machine. Don't I need to add the files on the server first? I'm assuming I don't have a local copy of the project yet.

Comment: If the files happen to be on the same server where you are hosting the git repository, then go ahead and make the bare repository, then clone that repo on the server, so you have two repos on there: the bare one, and a normal one. Add all the files to the normal one, and push to the bare one. Then everyone else should clone from the bare one.

Comment: So, I would take all the project files as normal (eg. via ftp) to my local machine? How do I then add them to the normal repo? Apologies, still trying to wrap my head around all of this.

Comment: I was thinking you would do it on the remote machine via `git add`, but if you can grab the files via ftp to your local machine, you don't have to worry about making the normal repo on the remote machine; just clone the bare repo to your local machine, copy the ftp'd files to you local repo, and add them all with `git add`. Then, commit and push. Does that make sense?

Comment: I am confused, and it's not you... so, for example, we get a website to take over from another company and it's on a live server. Disregarding the ftp option,  I go to the server, do git init --bare project.git   I then clone it to my desktop. I then on the remote git add . to add all the files, and then pull them to my desktop in the same local folder I created. A team member wants all the project files and does the same - git clone. Correct?

Comment: Close - on the remote, you would clone the bare repo to a normal repo, `git add .` the files to the normal repo, and push to the bare repo. Everyone else can then clone/pull from the bare repo and get the files. A good rule of thumb is that, _generally_, bare repos are for pushing/cloning/pulling from, and normal repos are for adding files to.

Comment: Thanks for all your help David! Finally got it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that, in your case, you should create your repository using **--bare** option. Try something like this:

```
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git init --bare
```

Then you're able to clone it like this:

```
git clone user@yourdomain.com:/path/project.git
```

Comment: Actually you don't need to explicitly mkdir a folder. A simple git init --bare project.git suffice. But still +1

Comment: WHat the hell is /path/project.git?